# select id from user in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I make a request in the database - select id from user;

If I do this in the database, I get the list id:

```
id:
26c940a1-7228-4ea2-a3bc-e6460b172040
5597cc3d-c948-48a0-b711-393edf20d9c0
7badc8f8-65bc-449a-8cde-855234ac63e1
867f0924-a917-4711-939b-90b179a96392
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a class named `User` is mapped to the `user` table, try

```
session.query(User.id).all()
```

This will return a list of named tuples, each with only an `id` field.

See the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#querying) for more examples.